# Paste leading common substrings from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

In Excel, Sheet1 I have the following column in one sheet that contains names:

[image]

In Sheet2 I have a column called substring as shown in the screenshot below (for simplicity I just use 1 row):

[image]

For each name in Sheet1, I want to check if it contains any of the substrings in Sheet2, which is "abreu" in this case. If the name contains the substring from Sheet2 AND the substring is in the beginning of the name, then paste the substring to the cell next to it. If the name doesn't contain the substring, then don't do anything. The desired output should look like the screenshot below:

[image]

I have tried VLOOKUP which doesn't quite work because it's either full match or partial match and none of which fit my case here. I also tried the SEARCH function which also doesn't detect whether the substring is in the beginning of the name. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does the substring always have 6 characters?

Comment: @teylyn no, the length of the substring could vary.

Comment: what if your sub-string has both `abreu` and `abre` or `aBRE`, i.e. a sub-string within another sub-string, which one do you want to return, and will the match be case sensitive?

Comment: @TerryW, it's case insensitive, and if there are 'abreu', 'abre' and 'aBRE', I will return the one that's minimum length. In this case it will be 'abre'.

Comment: To speed up the calculation you can consider using either VBA or Power Query. For VBA approach you may ask @BigBen for help. Let me know if you want to see a Power Query approach, it is not a very straight forward solution but I believe it should save you a lot of time running it compared to using formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. I have both lists on the same sheet, but you can easily modify the formula to reflect the 2-sheet setup.

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$3)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,LEFT(A2,LEN($D$2:$D$4)))),1))
```

[image]

You can also add an `IFERROR` to return `""` if no match.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen! This worked for my example so I accepted the answer. Is there a way to truncate this formula a bit? My actual worksheet has 24000 rows in first sheet and thousands of substrings in the second sheet, and it takes a very long time for the calculation.

Comment: Hmm - not that I'm sure of. It could probably could be converted to a VBA solution. Thousands of substrings will slow down the calculation, that's independent of the length of this formula. With VBA you could speed things up by reading that list of substrings into an array, comparing each cell on sheet1 to that array, and then immediately exiting when a match is found, saving some calculation.

Comment: if my substrings contain 'abreu' and 'abre', i.e. a sub-string within another sub-string, would your formula return the first one it saw (in this case, 'abreu')?

Comment: Yes. I wondered if your substrings might have this issue (again, this is not a defect of the formula, it's the setup you have and you have to decide which one to return, right)?